# How to use R find the closest date before specific date of matrix A? And 14 days after the specific date?

Tags: r, date

I’m a newbie in R. 
I have two dataset A and B.

```
A <- data.table::fread(
"
V1  DATE    ID
1   7/16/11 a
2   2/18/09 b
3   3/25/08 c
")

B <- data.table::fread(
"
V1  DATE    ID  Value
1   2013-06-13  a   109
2   2017-08-22  a   86
3   2017-09-15  a   88
4   2008-11-05  a   78
5   2009-02-17  a   74
6   2009-03-09  a   84
7   2009-03-17  a   81
8   2009-04-14  a   57
9   2009-04-21  a   65
10  2009-05-12  a   54
11  2009-06-08  a   54
12  2009-08-27  a   68
13  2011-08-26  b   199
14  2011-12-07  b   174
15  2012-01-31  b   66
16  2012-02-15  b   58
17  2012-04-17  b   59
18  2012-12-21  b   78
19  2013-01-14  b   91
20  2014-03-12  b   74
21  2014-08-28  b   98
22  2014-10-18  b   112
23  2010-12-15  b   36
24  2011-08-26  b   199
25  2011-12-07  b   174
26  2012-01-31  b   66
27  2012-02-15  b   58
28  2012-04-17  b   59
29  2015-05-08  c   105
30  2006-03-27  c   69
31  2007-03-12  c   104
32  2007-11-09  c   63
33  2008-03-25  c   239
34  2008-04-04  c   446
35  2008-04-09  c   354
36  2008-04-10  c   365
37  2008-04-11  c   366
38  2008-04-18  c   273
39  2008-04-28  c   271
40  2008-05-06  c   262
41  2008-05-19  c   72
42  2008-05-24  c   86
43  2008-06-20  c   47
44  2008-07-10  c   46
45  2008-08-06  c   55
46  2008-09-01  c   58
47  2008-09-29  c   56
48  2008-10-30  c   53
49  2008-12-09  c   71
50  2008-12-18  c   63
51  2009-01-14  c   60
52  2009-02-21  c   58
53  2009-03-28  c   54
54  2009-04-29  c   56
55  2009-04-30  c   59
56  2009-06-23  c   64
57  2009-07-24  c   69
58  2009-08-17  c   73
59  2009-10-04  c   127
60  2009-11-26  c   289
61  2009-12-02  c   277
62  2009-12-08  c   230
")
```

I tried  weeks to use R to:

1. find value from B which  `ID==A$ID`, and `B$DATE` is closest date *before or the same* date as `A$DATE`;
   The expected result is : `ID=c, DATE=2008-03-25, Value=239`
2. find value from B which `ID==A$ID`, and `B$DATE` is 14 days after `A$DATE`. If there is no exact date after 14 days, find the closest date's value (like 15, 16 or 17 days *after* `A$DATE`)
   The expected result is : `ID=c, DATE=2008-04-09, Value=354`

Comment: Dear Hongtao, can you please provide the data in a better form, e.g run dput(df1) and copy & paste the structure in the post. secondly, can you please provide the code that failed.

Comment: Also, please provide the expected output. In particular, the expected result for question 2 is unclear.

Comment: Actually, I can't code to solve my request. My expected output is like Uwe's code. But when I run his code, it turn out error.

Comment: The error message was due to OP's production data had not been coerced to class `data.table` beforehand as opposed to the sample datasets which were already data.tables because the were create by  `data.table::fread()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution using `dplyr`:

q1 and q2 corresponds to your two questions.

```r
library(dplyr)

A$DATE <- as.Date(A$DATE,format = "%m/%d/%y")

B$DATE <- as.Date(B$DATE)

BA <- left_join(B,A, by= c("ID"="ID"))

q1 <- BA %>%
  filter(ID %in% A$ID) %>%
  filter(DATE.x < DATE.y) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  arrange(desc(DATE.x)) %>%
  slice(1)

q2 <- BA %>%
  filter(ID %in% A$ID) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(as.numeric(DATE.x) - as.numeric(DATE.y) >= 14)

q1
#> # A tibble: 2 x 6
#> # Groups:   ID [2]
#>    V1.x DATE.x     ID    Value  V1.y DATE.y    
#>   <int> <date>     <chr> <int> <int> <date>    
#> 1    12 2009-08-27 a        68     1 2011-07-16
#> 2    32 2007-11-09 c        63     3 2008-03-25

q2
#> # A tibble: 48 x 6
#> # Groups:   ID [3]
#>     V1.x DATE.x     ID    Value  V1.y DATE.y    
#>    <int> <date>     <chr> <int> <int> <date>    
#>  1     1 2013-06-13 a       109     1 2011-07-16
#>  2     2 2017-08-22 a        86     1 2011-07-16
#>  3     3 2017-09-15 a        88     1 2011-07-16
#>  4    13 2011-08-26 b       199     2 2009-02-18
#>  5    14 2011-12-07 b       174     2 2009-02-18
#>  6    15 2012-01-31 b        66     2 2009-02-18
#>  7    16 2012-02-15 b        58     2 2009-02-18
#>  8    17 2012-04-17 b        59     2 2009-02-18
#>  9    18 2012-12-21 b        78     2 2009-02-18
#> 10    19 2013-01-14 b        91     2 2009-02-18
#> # ... with 38 more rows
```

Comment: q1 is not correct result. For example, the closest date for ID=c is 2008-3-25, while it find 2007-11-09.

Comment: @HongtaoLi Instead of revealing correct values one at a time in comments, you can edit the question to show full expected output.

Comment: change < to <=`filter(DATE.x < DATE.y) %>%`

Comment: I've edited my question and my expected output . thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Both questions can answered using a *rolling join* from `data.table`.

However, there are two important steps in preparing the data.

1. The date strings need to be converted to class `IDate` (or `Date`) to allow for *date arithmetic*. (`IDate` uses an integer representation to save memory).
2. The dataframes need to be coerced to `data.table` to enable the enhanced syntax. `setDT()` coerces a dataframe or tibble to data.table *by reference*, i.e., without copying.
   BTW: The sample datasets provided by the OP were already data.tables as the OP had used the `data.table::fread()` function.

Data preparation:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(A)[, DATE := as.IDate(DATE, "%m/%d/%y")]
setDT(B)[, DATE := as.IDate(DATE)]
```

Now, we can apply the *rolling join*:

```
B[A, on = .(ID, DATE), roll = +Inf, .(ID, DATE, Value)]
```

> ```
>    ID       DATE Value
> 1:  a 2011-07-16    68
> 2:  b 2009-02-18    NA
> 3:  c 2008-03-25   239
> ```

The result can be verified by printing `B` in proper order `B[order(ID, DATE)]`. The earliest date for `ID == "b"` in `B` is `2011-08-26`. So, there is no date in `B` *on or before* `2009-02-18`.

Please, note that the value in the `DATE` column is the reference date `A$DATE`,  *not* the  matching `B$DATE`.

---

**Edit** after clarification of the expected result by the OP:

Also the second question can be solved by a `rolling join` but the code requires three modifications:

1. The reference dates `A$DATE` need to be shifted by 14 days later.
2. We need a *backward* rolling join because the OP wants to find the closest date in `B` on or after the shifted reference date.
3. According to OP's expected result the result should contain the matching `B$DATE`.

With the additional requrements we get

```
B[A[, .(ID, DATE = DATE + 14)], on = .(ID, DATE), roll = -Inf, .(ID, DATE = x.DATE, Value)]
```

> ```
>    ID       DATE Value
> 1:  a 2013-06-13   109
> 2:  b 2010-12-15    36
> 3:  c 2008-04-09   354
> ```

Comment: Thanks. But when I run first two lines:
library(data.table)
A[, DATE := as.IDate(DATE, "%m/%d/%y")]
....
It turns out like:
    Error in :=(DATE, as.IDate(DATE, "%m/%d/%y")) : 
     Check that is.data.table(DT) == TRUE. Otherwise, := and :=(...) are defined for use in j, once only and in particular ways. See help(":=").

Comment: @HongtaoLi As you were using `data.table::fread()` to create your sample datasets I supposed that your production data also were `data.table` objects. I have edited my code and added calls to `setDT()` which coerces  a dataframe to `data.table` _by reference_, i.e., without copying.

Comment: It's ok. Thank you.